# Workflow deployed as WCF service on azure is stuck

Tags: azure, workflow-foundation-4

We have deployed Workflow as wcf service on azure and its suddenly throwing below error:

The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance has not yet been persisted to the instance store

One thing that we noticed is a record is getting inserted in below table, which should not happen
[System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[LockOwnersTable]

and this is causing the fields in workflow InstanceTable are getting set to NULL.
The fields like IsInitialized, BlockingBookmark are all null.

Comment: Are you using web apps or cloud service? Are you waking up an existing persistence or starting a new one? If the former, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536983/windows-workflow-4-correlation-query-includes-website-instance-name-in-instance. Basically, the IIS site name becomes part of the correlation Id, making it very tricky to host persistent WF on Azure. I fixed it by running on Cloud Services and renaming the IIS server on startup.

Comment: @Frans we are using web apps.

Comment: Then you are probably going to have a problem with persistence. Have a read of the linked question. It's enough to give your a headache, but does explain it in detail. Took me several days to figure out.